# Getting current day and day before

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to obtain the StartDate (Today) and EndDate (Yesterday). I have been trying to keep numbers formatted correctly for the day. I noticed however, the system doesn't like when there is a leading zero and fails when it subtracts 1 from something like "09", but works perfect with "10". How can I go about fixing this?

```
echo off

REM CurrentDate (END DATE)      -------------------------------------------------------------
Set dd=%date:~4,2%
Set mm=%date:~7,2%
Set yyyy=%date:~10,4%
set END_DATE=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd% 00:00 AM

echo %END_DATE%

REM CurrentDate - 1 (START DATE)  ------------------------------------------------------------
set m1dd=%date:~4,2%
set m1dd=09
echo %m1dd%
set /A m1dd -= 1
echo %m1dd%
Set m1dd=0%m1dd%
echo %m1dd%
Set m1dd=%m1dd:~-2%
echo %m1dd%
set START_DATE=%yyyy%-%mm%-%m1dd% 00:00 AM

echo %START_DATE%

pause
```

Comment: Explanation for down-vote please so that I can learn & create a better question in the future? Thanks.

Comment: How can something end before it has started?

Comment: Primarily you should research your topic prior posting, type `batch yesterday` in the search box above and you'll get plenty of results.

Comment: In your question "StartDate (Today) and EndDate (Yesterday)" should be "StartDate (Yesterday) and EndDate (Today)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Yesterday BATCH FILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22376408/set-yesterday-batch-file)

Comment: @Compo END_DATE < START_DATE

Comment: Your code does not take into account a change of month or year. Nor, will it work on leap days.

Comment: GAHHHHH. You are right. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch file uses a little trick with the XCOPY command to validate that the date is actually a valid date as you are subtracting 1 from YYYYMMDD.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set rand=%random%
md "dummy%rand%\empty%rand%"

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"

set /a y=%dt:~0,4%
set /a m=1%dt:~4,2%
set /a d=1%dt:~6,2%

REM set the number of days to substract
SET DAYS=1
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,%days%) DO CALL :loop

set subdate=%y%%m:~-2%%d:~-2%
echo Today is: %dt:~0,8%
echo Yesterday was: %subdate%

rd /s /q "dummy%rand%"
pause
endlocal
GOTO :EOF

:loop
  set /a d-=1

  if %d% lss 101 (
    set d=131
    set /a m-=1

    if %m% lss 101 (
      set m=112
      set /a y-=1
    )
  )

xcopy /d:%m:~-2%-%d:~-2%-%y% /t "dummy%rand%\empty%rand%" "dummy%rand%" >nul 2>&1 || goto loop

GOTO :EOF
```

Output

```
Today is: 20170905
Yesterday was: 20170904
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

You could utilise powershell from your batch file:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "TS=.ToString('yyy-MM-dd') + \" 00:00 AM\""
For /F "UseBackTokens=1*Delims=@" %%A In (`
    PowerShell "(Get-Date)%TS% + \"@\" + (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)%TS%"`
) Do Set "TD=%%A" & Set "YD=%%B"
Echo  %%TD%% = %TD%
Echo  %%YD%% = %YD%
Timeout -1
```

Comment: Is the `%TS%` for obfuscating or shorting - well it seems to serve both ;-) +1

Comment: That's was Great. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you do date calculations is not ideal. For a better date calculations you can refer to this [link](https://gist.github.com/santa4nt/660631).

If you are just looking for a quick fix to make your current code run, simply remove leading zeroes as follows:

```
echo off

REM CurrentDate (END DATE)      -------------------------------------------------------------
Set dd=%date:~4,2%
Set mm=%date:~7,2%
Set yyyy=%date:~10,4%
set END_DATE=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd% 00:00 AM

echo %END_DATE%

REM CurrentDate - 1 (START DATE)  ------------------------------------------------------------
set m1dd=%date:~4,2%
set m1dd=09
set /a m1dd=100%m1dd% %% 100
echo %m1dd%
set /a m1dd -= 1
echo %m1dd%
Set m1d=0%m1dd%
echo %m1dd%
Set m1d=%m1dd:~-2%
echo %m1dd%
set START_DATE=%yyyy%-%mm%-%m1dd% 00:00 AM

echo %START_DATE%

pause
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you should modify the system date/time format to yyyy/MM/DD

[Refer this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726738/change-date-and-time-format-via-command-prompt)